# Assert an element is not present in the dom using GEB

Tags: selenium, geb

I am trying to verify a page based on who logs in. Certain users have more security and will see more items on the page. When a user with lower security logs in, they will not see options. I need to verify those options are not present on the page.

I have a page object for the option that displays based on user security

```
testObject {$("#test")}
```

I have tried using isDisplayed()

```
boolean hidden =  testObject.isDisplayed()
assert !hidden
```

But I keep getting an error that says

> geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content
>   geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator' is not present

The error message is what I want to verify. The object is not present, and I need to verify that is true and pass the test.

Comment: Even with a page object you need to check for null

Comment: That is not necessary, Bill. My answer explains why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `required` option for your content element.

If the page is dynamic, maybe you also want to wait for a while before you let Geb decide that the element is empty. Checks for non-existence of elements can be tricky, because they could just pass because a dynamic element has not finished loading yet.

```java
testObject(required: false, wait: 2) { $("#test") }
```

In your Geb test you just do this (no helper method needed):

```java
given:
def page = to MyPage

expect:
page.testObject.empty
```

Comment: If I run page.TestObject.empty. it returns false. I needed to set required to false and then use isDisplayed in order to get my test to work.

Comment: Then probably you are not testing for the right object but for an empty container in your DOM which always exists. I tested my code, it does work as shown in my answer.